# Expand or collapse all sub menus regardless of whether all or some are already expanded or collapsed

Tags: jsf, primefaces, submenu

**Goal:**

We have a requirement to have an expand/collapse button/s to expand or collapse all SubMenus - This seems to work UNLESS one of the state are different.

**E.g:**

Menu states: true(expanded), true(expanded), true(expanded), true(expanded) will change to false(collapsed), false(collapsed), false(collapsed), false(collapsed) and vice versa with our current code.

**HOWEVER** -> true(expanded), **false(collapsed)**, true(expanded), true(expanded) will NOT change to false(collapsed), false(collapsed), false(collapsed), false(collapsed) and vice versa with our current code.

**Problem:**

I have an issue where is seems almost as if the view(xhtml) page does not update the JSF backing bean

**Code:**

xhtml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"     
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" >
    <h:head>     
        <title>Website</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <p:growl id="messages"/>
        <p:layout id="fullpagelayout" fullPage="true" >
            <p:layoutUnit id="layoutNorth" position="north" resizable="true" size="120" style="min-height: 120px; height: 120px;" >
                <ui:include id="northHeader" src="header.xhtml" />
            </p:layoutUnit> 
            <p:layoutUnit id="layoutWest" position="west" collapsible="true" resizable="true" style="min-width: 150px;">
                <h:form id="menuForm">                    
                    <p:commandButton id="expandBtn" value="Expand" action="#{mainMenuBean.changeMenuState(true)}" async="true" update="menuForm:mainMenu" styleClass="expandCollapseBtn" style="margin-bottom: 2px;" />
                    <p:commandButton id="collapseBtn" value="Collapse" action="#{mainMenuBean.changeMenuState(false)}" async="true" update="menuForm:mainMenu" styleClass="expandCollapseBtn" style="margin-bottom: 2px;" />
                    <p:panelMenu id="mainMenu" model="#{mainMenuBean.model}" />
                </h:form>
            </p:layoutUnit>
            <p:layoutUnit id="layoutCenter" position="center" style="padding: 5px; margin: 5px;" >                    
                <ui:include id="centerPanel" src="centerPanel.xhtml" />                    
            </p:layoutUnit>
            <p:layoutUnit id="layoutSouth" position="south" resizable="true" closable="true" size="30" >
                <ui:include id="southPanel" src="status.xhtml" />
            </p:layoutUnit>
        </p:layout>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

---

Backing bean:

---

```
    package /*PACKAGE*/

    /*imports*/

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class MainMenuBean implements Serializable {

    private MenuModel model;
    private MenuStateController stateController;
private String updateParam;

public MainMenuBean() {
    initBeans();
}

private void initBeans() {
    buildMainMenu();
}

public MenuModel getModel() {
    return model;
}

public void setModel(MenuModel model) {
    this.model = model;
}

public void buildMainMenu() {

    model = new DefaultMenuModel();
    stateController = new MenuStateController();
    updateParam = ":panelContents";

    // File Submenu and menu Items
    DefaultSubMenu fileSubMenu = new DefaultSubMenu("File");
    addMenuItem(fileSubMenu, "Logout", "logoutPage", "ui-icon-home", 
                "/login/login.xhtml?faces-redirect=true", false, false, updateParam, stateController);

    model.addElement(fileSubMenu);

    // Tools Submenu and menu Items
    DefaultSubMenu toolsSubMenu = new DefaultSubMenu("Tools");
    addMenuItem(toolsSubMenu, "Tool Page", "toolPage", "ui-icon-wrench", 
                "#{menuStateController.setPage('/content/tool.xhtml')}", true, true, updateParam, stateController);
    model.addElement(toolsSubMenu);


    // Search Submenu and menu Items
    DefaultSubMenu searchSubMenu = new DefaultSubMenu("Search");
    addMenuItem(searchSubMenu, "Search", "searchPage", "ui-icon-search", 
                "#{menuStateController.setPage('/content/search.xhtml')}", true, true, updateParam, stateController);
    model.addElement(searchSubMenu);

    // Help Submenu and menu Items
    DefaultSubMenu helpSubMenu = new DefaultSubMenu("Help");
    addMenuItem(helpSubMenu, "About", "aboutPage", "ui-icon-help", 
                "#{menuStateController.setPage('/content/about.xhtml')}", true, true, updateParam, stateController);
    model.addElement(helpSubMenu);

}

private void addMenuItem(DefaultSubMenu subMenu, String menuItemName, String id, String icon, 
        String commandName, boolean isAjax, boolean isAsync, String Update, MenuStateController stateController) {

    NEWMenuItem item = new NEWMenuItem(menuItemName, id, stateController);

    item.setId(id);
    item.setIcon(icon);
    item.setCommand(commandName);
    item.setAjax(isAjax);
    item.setAsync(isAsync);
    item.setUpdate(Update);
    subMenu.addElement(item);
}

   public void changeMenuState(boolean expanded) {
        for (MenuElement menuElement : model.getElements()) {
            if(menuElement.getClass() == DefaultSubMenu.class){
                if(menuElement instanceof DefaultSubMenu){
                    DefaultSubMenu subMenu = (DefaultSubMenu) menuElement;
                    if(!subMenu.isExpanded() == expanded){
                    subMenu.setExpanded(expanded);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

So essentially I would like the "expand" or "collapse" buttons to expand or collapse all sub menus regardless of whether all or some are already expanded or collapsed.

Hope this makes sense!